# How to pass multiple PHP variables to PHP in jQuery/Ajax? This is all my code

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

It's works fine within single page. But i can't pass nothing more. Like category in this case. Can't find nothing to solve this problem. Tried everything but can't find solution.

index.php

```
(function($){   
    $.fn.loaddata = function(options) {// Settings
        var settings = $.extend({ 
            end_record_text : \''.$lang['lang_30'].'\', //end of record text
            loadbutton_text : \''.$lang['lang_31'].'\', //load button text
            data_url        : \'fetch_category.php'\', //url to PHP page
            start_page      : 1 //initial page
        }, options);

        var el = this;  
        loading  = false; 
        end_record = false;     

        //initialize load button
        var load_more_btn = $(\'<button/>\').text(settings.loadbutton_text).addClass(\'load-button\').click(function(e){ 
            contents(el, this, settings); //load data on click
        });

        contents(el, load_more_btn, settings); //initial data load  
    }; 

    //Ajax load function
    function contents(el, load_btn,  settings){
        var record_end_txt = $(\'<div/>\').text(settings.end_record_text).addClass(\'end-record-info\'); //end record text

        if(loading == false && end_record == false){
            loading = true; //set loading flag on

            //temporarily remove button on click
            if(load_btn.type === \'submit\' || load_btn.type === \'click\'){
            }

            $.post( settings.data_url, {\'page\': settings.start_page}, function(data){ //jQuery Ajax post
                if(data.trim().length == 0){ //if no more records
                    el.append(record_end_txt); //show end record text
                    load_btn.remove(); //remove load button
                    end_record = true; //set end record flag on
                    return; //exit
                }
                loading = false;  //set loading flag off
                el.append(data).append(load_btn);  //append content and button
                settings.start_page ++; //page increment
            })
        }
    }

})
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?category=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^category category.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, but i still can't POST category variable to fetch_category.php file, just code looks more efficient. And can't find nothing any solutions to solve this problem with multi variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't"? Where are you trying to? What have you tried to debug the problem? And how is this related to MySQL? If posting the data fails already, there is absolutely no connection to MySQL

Comment: @CodeCandy Add an 'at'username to you comment so the person you are reacting to, as well as others, know who you are talking to. 
Now I'm no jQuery genius (I'm a vanilla js proponent :p) but I think that the `settings.start_page` variable you increment at the end will not increment the `settings.start_page` value you have set at the start. If you wish this to be a self executing function, I'ed say you need a `(jQuery)` right after the last closing bracket. Could be wrong, like I said not a jQuery genius.